# Shortcode appearing at top

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

Have a shortcode thats calling a custom post type to display on an area in a standard loop template.
problem I'm having is that the output is appearing above the what's in the page.

Can anyone help?

Code is:

```
function JDD_display_stores() {

    ob_start();

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'stores',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'store',
                'field' => 'slug'
            )
        )
    );

    $success = new WP_Query( $args );

    if( $success->have_posts() ) {

        while( $success->have_posts() ) {

            $success->the_post();

            ?>
                <h1><?php the_title() ?></h1>

                <div class='content'>

                    <?php the_content() ?>

                </div>

            <?php
            return $success;
        }
    }
    else {
        echo 'No stores have been added!';
    }
}

add_shortcode('display_stores', 'JDD_display_stores');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need **return** the titles and content rather than echoing it
(which `the_content()` and `the_title()` do)

like:

```
$output = '';

while( $success->have_posts() ) {
    $success->the_post();

    $output .= sprintf("<h1>%s</h1>", get_the_title()); 
    $output .= sprintf('<div class="content">%s</div>', get_the_content());

}

//reset the orignal main query
//see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query
wp_reset_query();

return $output;
```

..you'll need **get**_the_title() and **get**_the_content() for that.

Also take care, that you put the `return` **outside** the while loop,  otherwise you'll exit the function in the first iteration...

see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content
& http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title

Comment: return the_title();??

Comment: yes, but you'll need get_the_title() for that . updated the my answer

Comment: have tried the code but all that gets outputted is: /h1>
/div> in my h1 style